# Reading Band Interleaved Images From A URL In Matlab

Tags: matlab, web-applications

I am trying to read from a Web Map Server w/out using the mapping toolbox (more specifically, w/out using the WebMapServer object). I can construct the URL myself w/out problem and can just use imread for WMSs that return bmp files. However, one of the WMSs returns BIL files (Band InterLeaved) and imread() does not recognize it.

How can I read a BIL file from a URL w/out using the mapping toolbox?

Edit: Here is an example URL that I'd like to read:

http://www.nasa.network.com/elev?SERVICE=WMS&LAYERS=mergedAsterElevations&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&FORMAT=image%2Fbil&TRANSPARENT=FALSE&HEIGHT=1113&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&REQUEST=GetMap&WIDTH=925&BBOX=-118.545692,33.960524,-118.44569200000001,34.060523999999994&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&VERSION=1.3.0

Also, if I try to just grab the byte data w/ urlread and then write it to file, somehow some of the values are lost.

```
bytedata = urlread( mapurl );
fp = fopen( 'tmp.bil', 'w' );
fwrite( fp, bytedata, 'uint8' );
fclose( fp );
fp = fopen( 'tmp.bil', 'r' );
z = fread( fp, 'int16' );
imagesc( reshape( z, 925, 1113 )' );
```

The above displays an image similar to that returned by the mapping toolbox but there are regions that are set to a constant value that should not be.

Comment: Have you tried a simple google search for `matlab bandinterleaved` the first hit is http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/multibandread.html

Comment: @slayton: Yes, but it only reads files. I need to read from a URL.

Comment: Yea I get that. The first thing I'd try is to save the data from the URL as a temporary file and see if `multibandread` can open that tempo file.  Then if that works I'd read the source for `multibandread` and implement my own reader.

Comment: @slayton: I don't get the same values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above problem is to use urlwrite() rather than urlread(), since the latter will not properly handle binary data.

```
fname = tempname();
urlwrite(mapurl,fname);
fp = fopen(fname,'r');
map = reshape(fread(fp,'int16=>int16'),Ncols,Nrows)';
fclose(fp);
delete(fname);
```